# If $\vec a\times\vec b=\vec c,\vec b\times\vec c=\vec a$ and $|\vec a|=2$ then is $\vec a\times((\vec b+\vec c)\times(\vec b\times\vec c))=\vec0?$

Tags: vectors

> Let three vectors $\vec a,\vec b$ and $\vec c$ be such that $\vec a\times\vec b=\vec c,\vec b\times\vec c=\vec a$ and $|\vec a|=2$. Then which one of the following is not true?
>
> - A)$\;\vec a\times((\vec b+\vec c)\times(\vec b\times\vec c))=\vec0$
> - B)$\;$ Projection of $\vec a$ on $(\vec b\times\vec c)$ is $2$
> - C)$\;[\vec a\;\vec b\;\vec c]+[\vec c\;\vec a\;\vec b]=8$
> - D)$|3\vec a+\vec b-2\vec c|^2=51$

**Option A:**

LHS=$(\vec b+\vec c)(\vec a\cdot(\vec b\times\vec c))-(\vec b\times\vec c)(\vec a\cdot(\vec b+\vec c))$

Given that $\vec b\times\vec c=\vec a\implies\vec a\cdot(\vec b\times\vec c)=|\vec a|^2=4$

So, LHS=$4(\vec b+\vec c)-(\vec b\times\vec c)(\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec a\cdot\vec c)$

Given that $\vec a=\vec b\times \vec c\implies\vec a\cdot\vec b=0=\vec a\cdot\vec c$

So, LHS=$4(\vec b+\vec c)\ne0$

So, Option A) is not true, right? (I am not very sure about the nature of $\vec b+\vec c.$)

**Option B** and **option C** are easy for me to see that they are true.

**Option D:**

LHS=$(3\vec a+\vec b-2\vec c)\cdot(3\vec a+\vec b-2\vec c)=9|\vec a|^2+|\vec b|^2+4|\vec c|^2=36+|\vec b|^2+4|\vec c|^2$

Given $\vec a\times\vec b=\vec b\implies\vec c\times(\vec a\times\vec b)=\vec b\times\vec c=\vec a\implies\vec a|\vec b|^2-\vec b(\vec a\cdot\vec b)=\vec a\implies|\vec b|=1$

So, LHS=$37+4|\vec c|^2$

Given $\vec b\times\vec c=\vec a\implies(\vec b\times\vec c)\times\vec b=\vec a\times\vec b=\vec c\implies\vec c|\vec b|^2-\vec b(\vec b\cdot\vec c)=\vec c$

So, $\vec b\cdot\vec c=0$ i.e. the angle between $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ is $\dfrac\pi2$ (In fact, I had used this result while opening $|3\vec a+\vec b-2\vec c|^2$)

So, $|\vec b\times\vec c|=|\vec a|\implies|\vec c|=2$

So, LHS=$53\ne51$

So, option $D$ is not true.

Is there any other way to approach option A) and option D)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to solve this question (more like a variation on your answer to option D). Create an orthonormal system, with $\hat i$ along $\vec a$, $\hat j$ in the plane of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, perpendicular to $\hat i$, and $\hat k=\hat i\times\hat j$. Then $\vec a=2\hat i$, $\vec b=b_x\hat i+b_y\hat j$. From $\vec a\times \vec b=\vec c$ you get $\vec c=2b_y\hat k$. Then, if $\vec b\times\vec c=\vec a$ you get $b_x=0$ and $b_y=1$. Your result for part D is then immediately obtained. For part A, since $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ are not collinear $\vec b+\vec c\ne 0$. Or you can plug in the values for $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$ into the LHS expression.$$\vec a\times((\vec b+\vec c)\times\vec a)=4(\vec b+\vec c)=4\hat j+8\hat k\ne 0$$

Comment: Thank you, got it